# ¿Que distribución de linux es mas conveniente para un ordenador de bajos recursos?

Tags: linux

Me encantaría saber que distribución de linux me recomiendan para un ordenador con bajos recursos el ordenador posee actualmente 4 gb ram, un procesador pentium eh probado el uso de elementary os que es una de las distros "mas livianas" a comparación a ubuntu  sino me equivoco, lo afirmo como usuario, entonces me gustaría saber si es recomendable usar linux mint en este ordenador, ya que ubuntu en todas sus versiones suele colocarse lento o si es recomendable el uso de lubuntu, pregunto por que no se si tenga todas sus dependencias de paquetes  y entre otras como ubuntu, cuando digo que si tiene todas sus dependencias de paquetes me refiero a este ejemplo, en elementary os por defecto no puedo instalar repositorios ppa: por lo cual debo de instalarlo independientemente para poder instalar, a lo que quiero decir es que si hay una distro estable , completa y liviana cual me recomendarian usar?

Comment: Hola buenas tarde linux mint se te puede adaptar bien ya que sus requerimientos son si mal no recuerdo de 2gb de ram y 15 gb de disco duro.

Comment: Probare linux Mint al instalarlo que mirror deberia escojer cual seria el mas recomendable?

Comment: Te recomiendo Xubuntu

Comment: Yo el que uso para descargar es este [enlace](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=246)

Comment: si claro esta genial, pero cuando te pide download mirrors cual es el recomendable los de us?

Comment: Yo uso loe de US

Comment: De  tantos mirros de US cual es el mas recomendable Clarkson University,advancedhosters.com,Harvard School of Engineering,kernel.org,Linux Freedom,MetroCast Cablevision,pair Networks etc ... ??

Comment: yo uso cualquiera de esos no tengo distinción por ninguno

Comment: Listo muchas gracias ...

Comment: Deberías de probar [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), ya que XFCE consume muy pocos recursos y tienes la facilidad que proporciona Ubuntu en el caso de que no estés acostumbrado al uso de sitemas Unix. Si, aún así, no te gusta el rendimiento, ya apostaría por [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/), requiere de bastante menos. Como experiencia personal, entre los dos, elegiría el primero por personalización y diseño, y, si ya quieres ir a un Sistema Operativo más avanzado puedes intentar jugar con [Debian](https://www.debian.org/index.es.html), aunque no me la jugaría si no estás tan acostumbrado, puest